# Algorithm for 2D grid problem?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I will be honest, this is an assignment question but I just cant find a solution to it. Please remember I am not asking for the answer but simply some guidance.

Problem:
Design an algorithm that runs in O(n) time (linear) which can locate a single suspicious house (point) on a 2D grid. It is suspicious if it consumes equal or greater to the electrical consumption of its two vertical and two horizontal neighbors. Note: just wants one suspicious house to be returned

Solution:
Not even sure how to achieve such a solution. If you check n houses you also can check its four surrounding neighbors. 4n/n^2 which simplifies to 4/n. Meaning that as the grid expands it is less likely to find a suspicious house.

What I have tried:
- Different data structures (most are nlogn)
- Folding the grid (again nlogn)

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My mistake, the grid is (n x n) making the number of houses n^2, sorry for the confusion.

Edit2:

This is the question exactly, maybe I am reading it wrong?

The police are looking for houses which have particularly large elec-
tricity consumption. To simplify the problem, imagine that they are
investigating houses which are laid out on an n×n grid. Each house on
the grid has some electricity consumption, e(i, j). The police consider
the house suspicious if it has electricity consumption equal to or greater
than each of its vertical and horizontal neighbours. Design an algorithm
that runs in O(n) time and returns the location of a suspicious house.

Comment: I read it as a simple O(n) problem (where n = rows * cols)

Comment: What does the input look like? Are you just given a grid of values or something else?

Comment: OK, and now specify the "suspicious" part a little better. Is a house suspicious when it is simply consuming more than each of it's neighbours or more than the sum of 2|4 neighbours?

Comment: @Henk Holterman & @Winston Ewert Refer to edit2.

Comment: It is just O(N^2) to read the data. I don't think you can do it in O(N), when you have N^2 houses.

Comment: Given that this is an assignment, what level of class is it from? I.e. beginner programmer vs advanced algorithm.

Comment: Is it only me that finds it funny that if all houses have equal consumption all are "suspicious", and if instead one has lower consumption, that odd-one-out is the only that *isn't* suspicious?

Comment: @meriton, yeah its suspicious. It was realizing that suspiciousness that led me to figure out how to solve it. They'd only have that wierdness for a reason.

Comment: @leonid in the sense that binary search is O(log(n)), don't you think?

Answer (score 5):

You are basically looking for a house whose electricity use is a local maximum.  You can find one of those by starting at an arbitrary house and stepping to an adjacent house if its electricity use is higher (repeat until no adjacent house is higher).

This will take O(n) time on an n x n grid.

Edit: commenters are right, this could take O(n^2) time in the worst case.

Comment: I don't think that works. You may find a local maximum which is below the threshold but where another local maximum would be above.

Comment: @Winston: The question is for _a_ local max, not for the best.

Comment: @Keith, nice but it's homework. I think the OP should do the proof by himself.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much everyone. @Henk Holterman His answer was not a proof, just an algorithm description. I'm doing the proof on my own, now that I have direction.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, I see, I read the problem differently. I was thinking it was the sum of its neighbors. However, I don't see that finding the local maxima necessarily succeeds in O(n) steps. Two examples: 1st all houses except one have 0 usage, whereas the remaining house has 1. We'll have to scan over n^2 cells to find it. 2nd, A grid can be constructed that slowly increases in a zig zag pattern across the graph leading to I think n^2/2 cells having to be visited.

Comment: ... and just why is the lenght of any ascending path in O(n)?

Comment: @Winston: It says *equal* or greater than each neighbour, so your first pathological example is trivial to solve; any cell not adjacent to the global max is "suspicious". I do second your second observation, though.

Answer (score 3):

The local optima solution presented by Keith will not actually run in linear time. The problem is that it cannot guarantee that the path length is O(n).

However, consider what would happen if you looked at all of the houses in the middle row and column. Particular consider how you could use that in that to help your local optima solution.

(Complete solution not provided because, well, its an assignment) Nevertheless, a really neat problem. Kudos to its creator.

[EDIT: A hint]

The previously offered solution fails in cases like this:

```
X.XXX.XXX.X
X.X.X.X.X.X
X.X.X.X.X.X
X.X.X.X.X.X
XXX.XXX.XXX
```

where . is a really small electrical usage and and the x's are slowly increasing electrical usage.

What happens if we query the middle row?

```
X.XXX.XXX.X
X.X.X.X.X.X
&&&&&&&&&&&
X.X.X.X.X.X
XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Where the & is the houses we looked at. We've managed to slice through the path. If we were to start our hill climbing at the best point we found, we'd be able to avoid the long path. (But we still cannot guarantee the path is short enough)

[EDIT: A second hint]

Scan the middle row as mentioned. Take the largest value. Move up or down to a larger value (if you can't then that grid cell is a local optima and you are done). Now consider a path of increasing values. There is no way that path can cross that middle row again because all values in that row must be less then then the current cell. (Because the current cell must be larget then the largest of the values in the row). This means that we have essentially reduced the problem in half.

Comment: @user492986, I'm a little hesitant regarding how much help to give. Does your class have a policy regarding outside assistance?

Comment: Let me get this straight though. The 'failed' case is not n*n though, its k*n where k is some positive constant. Because we still are not checking ALL the spaces.

Comment: @user492986, k is not a constant because it gets bigger as n does. In particular, such a case requires that I have to visit every other column. K is thus about n/2 and the complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: Apparently it has to do with divide and conquer, one level, any ideas?

Comment: @user492986, oh I know the answer, I'm just giving hints out as its an assignment. Text updated with another hint.